# What's the name of the song that plays on Naruto episode 172 at 7:28?

Tags: naruto, music

What's the name of the song that plays on *Naruto* episode 172 at 7:28?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the scene where Isarabi attacks Naruto?

It's an unreleased track. There's an unofficial version [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1XQBPWNMwhI), titled "Predicament".

Answer (score 0):

From further investigation, I *think* that the name of the song is **Predicament**.  I’m not **100 °/o** sure though.